# Edge-mounted vias... or how is this called? And can PCBs services manufacture it?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, via, through-hole

[image: PCB through-holes (vias) are at the border]

As you can see, the through-holes (vias) are at the border of the inner cutout. (rendering is wrong of course, as vias are not cut)

I imagine a manufacturer first prints the board and then cuts it, so that will be no problem to produce - correct?

And how does one call such border/edge-mounted, cut-in-half vias?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are called "castellations", from their similarity to the battlements of castles.

[An example explanation from seeedstudio.](http://support.seeedstudio.com/knowledgebase/articles/910767-what-are-plated-half-holes-castellated-holes)

Comment: In some situations,  you may ask them to route the board without the replating that gives you the castellated holes. For example, I have done this for mounting holes which slightly overlap with the board edge from run to run and ask the MFG to route through it without replating to guarantee the board dimensions.